# How to build a regex to capture the contents between DIV?

Tags: regex

This is my test input string

```
Test code <div>Testing here. Div contents</div> Blah Blah <div>Second div</div>Blah
```

I need to capture the contents between . Please help me understand how to build the regex to accomplish this with some explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work.

```
(?<=<div>).*?(?=<\/div>)
```

demo - https://regex101.com/r/vnfpRV/1

Comment: Yes, this is finding the match. Could you please write a few lines on how you built this regex. Thanks Kaushik.

Comment: Just want to know what does '?<=' do?

Comment: @CodeForGood I provided a demo link, where you can see the explanation for this regex at right side.

Comment: ?<= is for positive look behind.

refer this link for understand what is "Positive and Negative Lookbehind
". https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html